# How to PERSIST all keys in Redis

Tags: redis

Using redis-cli or redsmin is it possible to PERSIST all keys in a specific db?

So far what I have seen is to PERSIST a single key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persisting all keys at once is not possible with redis. But you can achieve it with a lua script, by iterating over all the keys in a db and persisting them one by one. Instead of using keys command (which is blocking) you can use scan to achieve the same.